# M2 - How to add a block in category page before products prices block

Tags: magento2, blocks, template

I'm trying to add a block (with template) in category page before products prices block (`<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>` in **list.phtml**).

I've created **catalog_category_view.xml** layout:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.price.render.default">
            <block name="w1.block" as="w1.block" class="WaPoNe\HelloWorld\Block\Product\ListProductW1" template="WaPoNe_HelloWorld::product/price/discount.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

my **WaPoNe\HelloWorld\Block\Product\ListProductW1** block file:

```
<?php
namespace WaPoNe\HelloWorld\Block\Product;

class ListProductW1 extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getDiscountLabel()
    {
        return "Discount Label";
    }
}
```

and a simple template file (**product/price/discount.phtml**):

```
<?php 
echo $block->getDiscountLabel();
```

This doesn't not work but if I change `<referenceBlock name="product.price.render.default">` with `<referenceContainer name="content">`, for example, it works.

What is wrong?

Comment: You have to do it with calling block file inside template. May be i am not aware, No way through xml file.